# MySQL "Lock wait timeout exceeded" when calling certain query

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a MySQL 5.7 that has a set of tables, and I use the following query.

```
    SET innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 900;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS aggregated_table;

    CREATE TABLE aggregated_table AS
    SELECT
        itbl.u AS u,
        LEFT(itbl.e, 10) AS e,
        itbl.b AS b,
        itbl.c AS c,
        itbl.d AS d,
        itbl.ee AS ee,
        h,
        p,
        s,
        SUM(time_column) AS total_time
    FROM
        input_table AS itbl
    WHERE
        s = 1
        AND b = 0
    GROUP BY
        u,
        e,
        b,
        c,
        d,
        ee,
        h,
        p,
        s;
```

80% of times this query performs OK but sometimes `CREATE` fails with  `ERROR __main__: (1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')`, probably depending on the specific data found in the database at that particular moment. With the same database state, the error is always reproduced.

I would like to understand why precisely it might fail and how to safeguard the query against the infinite lock.

UPDATE: `EXPLAIN SELECT...` provides answer (JSON-formatted by my database client):

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "select_type": "SIMPLE",
    "table": "itbl",
    "partitions": null,
    "type": "ALL",
    "possible_keys": null,
    "key": null,
    "key_len": null,
    "ref": null,
    "rows": 56035815,
    "filtered": 1,
    "Extra": "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"
  }
]
```

`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` output: https://pastebin.com/ZNeRi6AY

Comment: What query fails - DROP or CREATE?

Comment: CREATE of course.

Comment: Can you post the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT...`?

Comment: do you mean EXPLAIN SELECT or EXPLAIN CREATE SELECT? @PeterKoltai

Comment: `EXPLAIN SELECT`

Comment: after the error 1205 execute this query to see which resource locked : **SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;** and post the result

Comment: @PeterKoltai I run the command and amended the question

Comment: @AskarIbragimov So this is a 56M rows table without any indexes that this query can use, resulting in full table scan, forces the engine to create temporary tables and file sorting. I don't have deep knowledge on innodb row locking but this is a very slow query. I would try to add indexes.

Comment: @BerndBuffen status is https://pastebin.com/ZNeRi6AY.

Answer (score 0):

This composite index is likely to help:

```
INDEX(s, b)   -- (in either order)
```

The problem *seems* to be that it took more 900 seconds to read about 56M rows.

That is a rather monstrous `GROUP BY`, is it meaningful, or a workaround for `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`?

How much RAM do you have?  How big is the table?

If this "aggregated" ("Summary") table can be built incrementally (as in update each night with the day's data), the timeout can be very efficiently avoided.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables  If you can do it this way, I would *not* the index I suggest, but instead, use an id or date to control which rows are read each night, not worrying about filtering on `s` and `b`.

Comment: Tried creating an index, also increasing  innodb_lock_wait_timeout. Turns out that `ALTER TABLE input_table ADD INDEX (s,b);` causes the same "lock timeout" error. Could you suggest how to fight this?

Comment: @AskarIbragimov - Increase the timeout significantly.  The `ADD INDEX` is a one-time task.  1 day = 86400 seconds; if that times out, then I am missing something significant.